# How to extract Sheet names from Excel file using "com.crealytics.spark.excel" in Databricks (PySpark)

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have an Excel file in the azure datalake ,I have read the excel file like the following

```
ddff=spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
               .option("header", "true")\
               .option("sheetName","__all__")\
               .option("inferSchema","true")\
               .load("abfss://dev@stopsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/file.xlsx")
```

Now Iam confused how to get just the sheetnames from that Excel file,is there any direct function to do that ?

Comment: Can you elaborate, are you want to select or read only specified sheet Name.

Comment: I have 4 sheets in that Excel file , i need the sheet names not the data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the github [link](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel#:%7E:text=import%20com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader) for spark-excel.. the following code should work - please try it...Code directly taken from the github page.

```scala
import com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader
val sheetNames = WorkbookReader( Map("path" -> "Worktime.xlsx")
                               , spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
                               ).sheetNames
val df = spark.read.excel(
  header = true,
  dataAddress = sheetNames(0)
)
```

Comment: This code @rainingdistros in scala buit its throwing error in pyspark stating no parameter sheetNames exists in  com.crealytics.spark.excel

Answer (score 0):

*I reproduce the same in my environment with sample data. I got this output.*

> **Please follow the below steps. To resolve this issue :**

**Step1:** *Mount your storage account with Azure data bricks:*

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://<container_name>@<stoarge_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/<mount_path>",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<stoarge_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net":"<Access_key>"})
```

**Step 2:** *Use `dbutils.fs.ls` to access the whole mount path:*

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/<mount_path>")
```

[image]

> **Note:** **Use "/dbfs", instead of "dbfs:"**: The function expects a local file path

**For example**, *This is my actual file path: `dbfs:/mnt/dem/read-employees-csv.xlsx`. I modified the file path like this  `/dbfs/mnt/dem/read-employees-csv.xlsx`. And also make sure to install `openpyxl` and `fsspec` . Use this code to install packages : `pip install openpyxl`and `pip install fsspec`*

> **Now, execute the below code. You will get the list of sheets:**

**Code:**

```
import pandas
x1 = pandas.ExcelFile('/dbfs/mnt/dem/read-employees-csv.xlsx')
print(x1.sheet_names)
```

[image]

Comment: Clearly mentioned using com.crealytics.spark.excel not pandas

Comment: hi @Surya Teja532, AFAIK there might be no way to do this using `com.crealytics.spark.excel`. better convert spark to pandas.